# How to get questions present on mutiple categories using sql?

Tags: mysql

```
 SELECT faq_categories.id AS category_id, faq_categories.categories_name, faq_questions.id, 
 faq_questions.question, faq_questions.answer
 FROM faq_questions
   LEFT JOIN users ON users.certID = faq_questions.certID
   LEFT JOIN faq_categories ON faq_categories.id = faq_questions.categories 
   WHERE faq_questions.certID LIKE '%0%'
   and faq_questions.categories IN (1,2,3,4)
   GROUP BY faq_questions.question;
```

This query gets questions based on categories and userCERTID.

```
 How to modify this query .For example to get questions present on mutiple categories. For 
   `Example if question 1 is in both category 1 and category 2.Then result should be category1 
   question1 and category 2 question1`

Existing
category_name   question
Business          q1
Business          q2

Desired Result
Category_name   question
Business          q1
Business          q2
new               q1
sample            q2
```

How to modify this query .For example to get questions present on mutiple categories. For
`Example if question 1 is in both category 1 and category 2.Then result should be category1  question1 and category 2 question1`

Comment: having count(faq_categories.id) > 1 ?

Comment: If you want to return multiple rows for `question1` then you need to remove the `GROUP BY`, or add `faq_categories.id` to the `GROUP BY`. You have not provided relevant DDL or any sample data, so it is impossible to say which is the right way for your scenario.

Comment: Please remove the comment, as it adds nothing helpful. Sample data and expected output should be provided in text form ([markdown tables](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#tables) and/or `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements). Your current query is non-deterministic, as it seems unlikely that you have a unique key on `faq_questions.question`, and there are columns in the SELECT list which are neither aggregated, nor functionally dependent on the columns in the GROUP BY clause. Read [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To acheive this you need another pivot table like category_questions to store
category_id and question_id using foreach.Then you can  retreive questions present
on  mutiple categories using left join pivot table.